# Getting ERROR while setting up FSH console tool

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-7.0, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to install latest FullStackHero FSH console tool. I have all the prequsites like .NET 7 and Nodejs (latest) installed in my machine. Now when I tried to install the FSH console via the cmd prompt I see the below error :

C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\fafa2e0f-f7fc-490b-b7b4-7ec62eb73669\restore.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load
the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/symphonyvsts/_packaging/deloitte-nuget/nuget/v3/index.json.
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'fsh.cli' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

- You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
- A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
- The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
- You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
I have already installed the FullStackHero WebAPI Boilerplate with .NET 6 version.

https://fullstackhero.net/dotnet-webapi-boilerplate/general/overview/

Can you please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mukesh for providing me the resolution to this issue which can be found at : https://github.com/fullstackhero/dotnet-webapi-boilerplate/issues/855